# Please tell me the way to match the size of ()

Tags: spacing, equations

I want to match the size of the bracket.
I am not good at English.

[image]

```
\left(
    \begin{array}{lll}
    \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^4x_i^4 & \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^4x_i^3 & \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^4x_i^2 \\
     & \\
    \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^4x_i^3 & \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^4x_i^2 & \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^4x_i \\
     & \\
    \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^4x_i^2 & \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^4x_i   & \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^4 1
    \end{array}
    \right)
    \left(
    \begin{array}{c}
    a \\
    b \\
    c
    \end{array}
    \right)
    =
    \left(
    \begin{array}{l}
    \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^4x_i^2y_i \\
    \\
    \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^4x_iy_i \\
    \\
    \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^4y_i
    \end{array}
    \right)
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please add the compilable code you have so far!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a vertically centered `rule` of 0pt width. Also, remove all `\displaystyle`s and use `\limits`. Finally, you needn't add extra blank lines `\\`s.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\mrule{\vcenter{\hbox{\rule{0pt}{27pt}}}}

\[
\left(
    \begin{array}{lll}
    \sum\limits_{i=1}^4x_i^4 & \sum\limits_{i=1}^4x_i^3 & \sum\limits_{i=1}^4x_i^2 \\
    \sum\limits_{i=1}^4x_i^3 & \sum\limits_{i=1}^4x_i^2 & \sum\limits_{i=1}^4x_i \\
    \sum\limits_{i=1}^4x_i^2 & \sum\limits_{i=1}^4x_i   & \sum\limits_{i=1}^4 1
    \end{array}
    \right)
    \left(
    \begin{array}{c}
    a \mrule\\
    b \mrule\\
    c \mrule
    \end{array}
    \right)
    =
    \left(
    \begin{array}{l}
    \sum\limits_{i=1}^4x_i^2y_i \\
    \sum\limits_{i=1}^4x_iy_i \\
    \sum\limits_{i=1}^4y_i
    \end{array}
    \right)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also, another more-readable form using `\displaystyle` at column specification:

```
\newcommand\vp{\vphantom{\sum_{i=1}^4x_i^4}}    
\[
\left(
    \begin{array}{>{\displaystyle}l >{\displaystyle}l >{\displaystyle}l}
    \sum_{i=1}^4x_i^4 & \sum_{i=1}^4x_i^3 & \sum_{i=1}^4x_i^2 \\
    \sum_{i=1}^4x_i^3 & \sum_{i=1}^4x_i^2 & \sum_{i=1}^4x_i \\
    \sum_{i=1}^4x_i^2 & \sum_{i=1}^4x_i   & \sum_{i=1}^4 1
    \end{array}
    \right)
    \left(
    \begin{array}{>{\displaystyle}c}
    a \vp \\
    b \vp \\
    c \vp 
    \end{array}
    \right) =
    \left(
    \begin{array}{>{\displaystyle}l}
    \sum_{i=1}^4x_i^2y_i \\
    \sum_{i=1}^4x_iy_i \\
    \sum_{i=1}^4y_i
    \end{array}
    \right)
\]
```

[image]

Comment: Increasing the value of `\arraystretch` somewhat might be a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand\xstrut{\vphantom{\sum\limits_i^4}}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{pmatrix}
\sum\limits_{i=1}^4 x^4_i & \sum\limits_{i=1}^4 x^3_i\\ 
\sum\limits_{i=1}^4 x^3_i & \sum\limits_{i=1}^4 x^2_i\\ 
\sum\limits_{i=1}^4 x^2_i & \sum\limits_{i=1}^4 x_i\\ 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a\xstrut \\ b\xstrut \\ c\xstrut
\end{pmatrix}
=
\cdots
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It might be helpful if you provided a few sentences to state how you've modified the OP's code.

Answer (score 2):

Some suggestions:

- Don't use `\displaystyle` to generate "large" summation symbols; the ordinary size of the summation symbol is good enough for the present example.
- I can't see the point of listing both the upper and lower limits of summation, twelve [12!] times in all. Indicating that the summation index is `i` should suffice. (In fact, providing an explicit summation index may not be necessary either.) If you're really concerned that your readers could be unsure of what the upper and lower limits of the summations are, just provide that information in a sentence, either right before or right after this system of equations.
- Don't insert blank rows to create extra (vertical) spacing. Instead, reset the value of `\arraystretch` to some number greater than 1. In the example below, I set this parameter to 1.5.
- For a more compact look, use `pmatrix` environments, not `array` environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'pmatrix' environment
\begin{document}
\[
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{pmatrix}
    \sum_i x_i^4 & \sum_i x_i^3 & \sum_i x_i^2 \\
    \sum_i x_i^3 & \sum_i x_i^2 & \sum_i x_i   \\
    \sum_i x_i^2 & \sum_i x_i   & \sum_i 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
    a \\
    b \\
    c
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
    \sum_i x_i^2y_i \\
    \sum_i x_iy_i   \\
    \sum_i y_i
\end{pmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you everyone! 
This is final form based on opinions!!!
ありがとうございました。

[image]

```
\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{array}{lll}
    \sum\limits_{i=1}^4x_i^4 & \sum\limits_{i=1}^4x_i^3 & \sum\limits_{i=1}^4x_i^2 \\
    \sum\limits_{i=1}^4x_i^3 & \sum\limits_{i=1}^4x_i^2 & \sum\limits_{i=1}^4x_i \\
    \sum\limits_{i=1}^4x_i^2 & \sum\limits_{i=1}^4x_i   & \sum\limits_{i=1}^4 1
    \end{array}
    \end{pmatrix}
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \begin{array}{c}
    a \xstrut \\
    b \xstrut \\
    c \xstrut
    \end{array}
    \end{pmatrix}
    =
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \begin{array}{l}
    \sum\limits_{i=1}^4x_i^2y_i \\
    \sum\limits_{i=1}^4x_iy_i \\
    \sum\limits_{i=1}^4y_i
    \end{array}
    \end{pmatrix}
```